# preg_replace_callback match both multi line and single line html elements

Tags: php, regex, dom, preg-replace-callback

I need to parse HTML and remove newlines inside of any attributes. I've tried to use the `ism` switch but it returns all of my strings instead of elements.

Here is the HTML I am working with:

```html
<element type="contentlist" name="content1" template="
    <div class='content-item'>
        <img src='{thumb 128 128}' width='128' height='128' default='files/thumb/default.jpg' />
        <div class='title'>{title}<small>{title_description}</small></div>
        <div class='author'>{author}</div>
        <div class='views'>{views}</div>
        <div class='created_date'>{created_date %Y %B %d %A}</div>
        <div class='edited_date'>{edited_date %Y %B %d %A}</div>
        <div class='abstract'>{abstract 120}</div>
        <div class='tags'>{tags}</div>
        <div class='category'>{category}</div>
        <a class='readmore' href='{link}'>{readmore}</a>
    </div>" description="test html" />
<element type="video" name="VIDEO1" description="test html" folder="files/upload" file="vid" autoplay width="1024" loop="false" />
<element type="html" name="html1" description="test html" />
<element type="image" name="image2" hint="" description="" width="800" height="600" file="test2.jpg" folder="files/upload" />
<element type="text" name="text1" description="test text 1" max-length="256" max-words="50" />
<element type="slickslider" name="slider1" description="test text 1" />
<element type="list" name="list1" description="Menu" text-wrapper="span" text-class="text-center" class="xyz" ul-class="ul" li-class="li" />
<element type="gallery" name="gallery1" description="test text 1" />
```

And the regex that I used and worked for single line is:

```regex
/<element.*\/>/m
```

Comment: [Regex is not the correct tool for parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) [**instead use DOMDocument**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: @NarendrasinghSisodia DOMDocument cant parse multiline html attributes, so i decided to cast multiline attributes to single line before pass to DOMDocument.

Comment: DOMDocument **can** parse multiline html attributes